# Permutation and counting techinques

Tags: combinatorics

A bookshelf has 15 books. in how many ways can 4 books be removed such that no two adjacent books are chosen?
I started to solve the question by saying that the first book can be slected in 15 ways, the second one can be selected in 13 ways,the third one in 11 ways and the fourth one in 9 ways.
Total number of ways:15*13*11*9=19305.
However the correct answer must be 495.
Can you explain why my counting technique is false and provide me with hints about the correct one?

Comment: Hint by example: if the second book from the left is chosen first, there are only 12 ways the second book can be chosen.  If the second book is chosen as the fifth book from the left, there are only 9 ways the third book can be chosen.   However... you still won't come up with 495 combinations; there must be some other condition to get you down to that.

Comment: there is  no other condition since we got this question in a previous exam.

Comment: I am incorrect!  A simple simulation revealed the truth to me.  I'll work out the math later on...

Comment: Your over-counting error is that in counting the number of ways that the second one can be selected. If the first one was one the left-most book, then yes there are 13 ways to select the second. However if, (for example) the first book selected was the second-most from the left, then there are only 12 ways to select the next book.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the [stars and bars](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618491/distribute-n-identical-objects-into-r-distinct-groups) method of counting.

Consider the 4 books you select as bars and the 11 remaining books as stars.  That is, we have need to arrange 4 bars and 11 stars, under the constraint that between any two bars there is at least one star.

There are $3$ spaces between the bars, so there must be 3 stars between them.

That now simply requires us to fix the remaining 12 objects (8 stars and 4 bars).

We can do this in $\binom{12}{4}=495$ ways.

The obviously generalises to the following:

For $n\ge2m-1$, there are  $\dbinom{n-m+1}{m}$  ways to select $m$ non-consecutive items from a set of $n$ items.